# jquery form submit no effect at all

Tags: jquery

using the jquery `.submit()` on my form has no effect at all. i even checked other javascripts at my site to be sure the method isn't overwrited. the console is empty with no errors, too. my code:

```
<form method='POST' id='manualform'>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="hiddensubmit" style="display:none;"/>
                    <div>$MANUAL$</div>
                    <div class="space20"></div>
                    <input class="required email" id="emailinput" type="text" name="email" placeholder="meno@email.com" style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:white;width:250px;height:40px;background-color:black;opacity:0.5;padding-left:10px;" />
                    <div class="space20"></div>
                    <div
                        style="height: 50px; width: 300px; background-image: url('img/wow_img_pdf_icon.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 10px top; padding-top: 5px;">
                        <a id="action3" style="display: block; margin-left: 110px;"
                            >$STAHNOUT$</a>

                    </div>
                </form>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#action2').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: 20,
                fixed: function(){$('#hiddenfixed').css('display','');$('#action2').css('background-position','bottom');}   ,
                preUnfixed :function(){$('#hiddenfixed').css('display','none');$('#action2').css('background-position','top');} 
            });

            $('#action3').click(function(){     
                $('#manualform').validate({                 

                });             
                if(!($('#manualform').valid())) return false;
                else {
                    $('#hiddensubmit').attr('value','submit');
                    $('#manualform').submit();
                }                   
            });
        });
```

even when i try to redefine the submit event with `$('#manualform').submit(function(){alert(1);});`, no effect at all. i'm really desperate with nerves on the edge, please help

Comment: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation and https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Comment: where is <input type="submit"> ?

Comment: @web2008 does it matter? because the submit event is called by the <a> tag. anyway, the submit input is there at the second line and it's with `display:none` style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my workaround for this:
instead of `$('#manualform').submit();` do `$('#hiddensubmit').click();`.

my guess is some other javascript might have re-declared the submit() call, but i couldn't find it. still remains a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today and I discovered that it was because the name attribute of the submit button is "submit", same as in your example.

I haven't tested this in newer versions of jQuery, but I saw this while working on a legacy site that's still using jQuery 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the validate call outside of the click function. It only needs to be called once on page load.

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/n4MRM/

```
$('#manualform').validate();

$('#action3').click(function() {
    console.log('link clicked');
    if($('#manualform').valid()) {
        $('#hiddensubmit').attr('value', 'submit');
        console.log('form submitted');
        $('#manualform').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: thx for the answer, didn't work. still the same problem - submit event does not even react at all. even if i change it to `$('#manualform').submit(function(){alert(1);});`